# White background shows during 1 sec when keyboard closes on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-softkeyboard

When I tap to close the virtual keyboard, white background is shown on that place for 1 second.

I use `Activity(WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize)` to push “Done” button above the virtual keyboard but see a white background.

If I use `Activity(WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan)` there is no white background, but there is no "Done" button above.

How to fix a white background using AdjustResize?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/itemsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/doneButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Theme:

```
  <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#f2f2f2</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#f2f2f2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#f2f2f2</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/blue</item>

  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#979797</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: It could be related to your Theme (background color). Can you add code for the theme that you are using?

Comment: @Froyo I have added

Comment: Can you add code for `AppTheme.Base` as well?

Comment: @Froyo done AppTheme.Base

Comment: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` is light color theme and has a white background. You could try `Theme.AppCompat` for dark background. Or set `android:background="#your_color"` in your theme. If your activity / fragment layouts have a background color, it would double render background twice which is not recommended.

Comment: I solved the problem using the code below:
`FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content).RootView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);`
@Froyo thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the code below:

```
FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content).RootView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
```

**Edit 13-06-23:**

In your `MainActivity.kt`:

```
window.decorView.rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue by yourself, please mark your reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: If you set the code in proper case-sensitive letters, others can copy paste

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an old question but the way I did it was setting the android:windowBackground in to the right color:

```
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will solve your problem in **jetpack compose**

```
val transparentColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
window.decorView.rootView.setBackgroundColor(transparentColor)
```

Comment: Add an explanation to your answer.